# Passing state as parameter to a ring handler?

Tags: dependency-injection, clojure, compojure, ring

How does one inject state into ring handlers most conveniently (without using global vars)?

Here is an example:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/api/fu" [] (rest-of-the-app the-state)))

(def app
  (-> (handler/api main-routes)))
```

I would like to get `the-state` into the compojure handler for `main-routes`. The state might be something like a map created with:

```
(defn create-app-state []
  {:db (connect-to-db)
   :log (create-log)})
```

In a non ring application I would create the state in a main function and start injecting it, or parts of it, as function parameters to the different components of the application.

Can something similar be done with ring's `:init` function without using a global var?

Comment: Are you looking for a per session state or global state?

Comment: global - same lifetime as the :init and :destroy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've seen this done a couple of ways. The first is using middleware that injects the state as a new key in the request map. For instance:

```
(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/api/fu" [:as request]
    (rest-of-the-app (:app-state request))))

(defn app-middleware [f state]
  (fn [request]
    (f (assoc request :app-state state))))

(def app
  (-> main-routes
      (app-middleware (create-app-state))
      handler/api))
```

The other approach is to replace the call to `defroutes`, which behind the scenes will create a handler and assign it to a var, with a function that will accept some state and then create the routes, injecting the state as parameters to function calls within the route definitions:

```
(defn app-routes [the-state]
  (compojure.core/routes
    (GET "/api/fu" [] (rest-of-the-app the-state))))

(def app
  (-> (create-app-state)
      app-routes
      api/handler))
```

Given a choice, I'd probably go with the second approach.

Comment: Thanks! The second approach seems to be a good fit. The first one feels a bit hack-ish.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Alex described some routing frameworks for `ring` have a place for additional arguments which can be accessed by all handlers. In `reitit` this would work by putting custom objects under `:data`:

```
 (reiti.ring/ring-handler
   (reiti.ring/router
    [ ["/api"
      ["/math" {:get {:parameters {:query {:x int?, :y int?}}
                      :responses  {200 {:body {:total pos-int?}}}
                      :handler    (fn [{{{:keys [x y]} :query} :parameters}]
                                    {:status 200
                                     :body   {:total (+ x y)}})}}]] ]
    {:syntax    :bracket
     :exception pretty/exception
     :data      {:your-custom-data your-custom-data
                 :coercion   reitit.coercion.spec/coercion
                 :muuntaja   m/instance
                 :middleware []}}))
```

In your handler you're supposed to only work with `:parameters`, but you will be able to access your custom data by selecting `:reitit.core/match` and `:data`. The argument that the handler receives is based entirely on this:

```
(defrecord Match [template data result path-params path])
(defrecord PartialMatch [template data result path-params required])
```

Answer (score -1):

The "correct" way to do this is to use a dynamically bound var. You define a var with:

```
(def ^:dynamic some-state nil)
```

And then you create some ring middleware which binds the var for each handler call:

```
(defn wrap-some-state-middleware [handler some-state-value]
  (fn [request]
    (bind [some-state some-state-value]
      (handler request))))
```

You would use this to inject dependencies by using this in your 'main' function where you launch the server:

```
(def app (-> handler
             (wrap-some-state-middleware {:db ... :log ...})))
```

Comment: You're going to get into a lot of state management using dynamic. This can cause some serious issues later.