# How to use figwheel with a ring-handler that's a component?

Tags: clojure, ring

I'd like to use [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) to reload the frontend of an all-clojure project I'm playing with.

The backend serves a REST api and is organized as a bunch of [components](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) from which I create a system in my `main` function (I use [duct](https://github.com/weavejester/duct) to create the handler component). I want to pass state to my handlers using closures, but the only means of configuring figwheel to use my handler seems to be setting the [ring-handler](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#fighweel-server-side-configuration) key in `project.clj`, and this requires that I pass a handler that is defined in a namespace at `lein` startup time.

So - is there a way to configure figwheel when I am doing my component startup? I'm still very new at Closure so it's likely I'm missing something in plain sight.

[Passing state as parameter to a ring handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776462/passing-state-as-parameter-to-a-ring-handler) is a similar question, but the answer there involves binding the handler a var at the top-level of a namespace, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Figwheel doesn't need to be a handler. You can wrap a component that autobuilds while your server is up and running by dissecting [this](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#using-figwheel-from-the-repl) code into a component, a dependency to your server component so that it starts first. Note that this isn't officially supported. Running `lein figwheel` from the shell to boot a seperate JVM is the conventional usage.

If you are using Stuarts component lib I'd recommend to wrapping the ring handler from within a server component rather than via project.clj. Use [this project or adapt the code snippet](https://github.com/weavejester/ring-jetty-component/blob/master/src/ring/component/jetty.clj) for a jetty component.

Notice that figwheel is devtooling, so in production you most likely want to serve a compiled js file built with e. g. [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild).

Answer (score 0):

James Reeves made a component for figwheel [here](https://github.com/duct-framework/duct-figwheel-component)

> Duct-Figwheel-Component
>   A component for the Figwheel development tool, designed to be used in the Duct framework (but can be used in any component-based system).
>
> ### Installation
>
> Add the following dependency to your project.clj:

`[duct/figwheel-component "0.3.3"]`